# Symfony2 - Doctrine Entity Subdirectories

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Basically, i have a branch of code that connects to three different entity managers (and subsequently, three different MySQL databases). 
Unfortunately, two of the databases have tables that are named he same thing, so i cant have all the entities in the same directory, and for structure, id like to avoid that anyways.

So, my question is... How would i set it up so i can have a single entity bundle, with sub-directories under `Entity\` and `Resources\config\doctrine\`

e.g.

```
Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\DB1\Test.php
Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\DB1\Acme.php
Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\DB2\Test.php
Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\DB2\Foo.php
Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\DB3\Bar.php
```

and the same idea for `Resources\config\doctrine\`

The configs are very vague on what to do here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the bundle to store entities, I'd rather suggest to store them outside. This way you'd decouple them from the framework.

In both cases configuration is similar. Reference is accessible in [the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration).

Here's an example:

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            AcmeDB1:
                type:       xml
                is_bundle:  false
                dir:        %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Entity/DB1/config
                prefix:     Acme\Entity\DB1
                alias:      AcmeDB1
            AcmeDB2:
                type:       xml
                is_bundle:  false
                dir:        %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Entity/DB2/config
                prefix:     Acme\Entity\DB2
                alias:      AcmeDB2
```

Few notes:

- dir refers to the mapping directory, if you use annotations this should be directory where your entities are placed
- prefix is part of your entity's namespace and it should be unique
- alias makes that you can refer to your entities with shorter namespaces, like AcmeDB1:User

Comment: forgot to mention, im importing the yml files from the database. so how does the `doctrine:mapping:import` command work with this?

Comment: Just try. Worst case you'd have to move the files to appropriate directories and later update the entity namespaces and mappings to reflect the new location. It shouldn't be an issue since you have to do it once. If you have lots of entities you can automate the update with a shell script.

Comment: I actually went ahead and did a pull request on the DoctrineBundle code, adding support for subspacing in the `doctrine:mapping:import` command. waiting to see

Answer (score 7):

You only need to rename your doctrine configurations files.

So for example:

- `Bundle/Entity/DB1/User.php`
- `Bundle/Entity/DB2/User.php`

results in the respective config files (.yml in this case, change as you please)

- `Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine/DB1.User.orm.yml`
- `Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine/DB2.User.orm.yml`